# Counting specific text mentions in a column with multiple filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel

[Attached here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IujBc3lKPGjJBsJJnTBg_HN3mBT4oUDt/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115114088789011376318&rtpof=true&sd=true) I have an Excel sheet with 3 columns labeled `Titles`, `Industry`, and `Responses`. These were from a survey where users could selection multiple options in `Responses`. The answers (`Ans_1`, `Ans_2`, etc.) are separated by a semicolon in the same column.

**Sample Data**
<sub>**Note:** *Actual data is hundreds of rows*</sub>

| Titles | Industry | Responses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Title_2 | Industry_1 | Ans_3;Ans_4;Ans_7;Ans_9;Ans_13; |
| Title_1 | Industry_5 | Ans_4;Ans_13; |
| Title_3 | Industry_1 | Ans_7; |
| Title_2 | Industry_5 | Ans_3;Ans_4;Ans_7;Ans_9; |
| Title_2 | Industry_1 | Ans_3;Ans_2;Ans_10; |
| Title_4 | Industry_2 | Ans_6;Ans_7;Ans_8; |
| Title_4 | Industry_1 | Ans_2;Ans_3;Ans_9; |

How do I build a table where I can count the specific answers under `Responses` (for e.g. only mentions of `Ans_1;`) by filtering for `Title` or `Industry` or both? The format for required tables are in `Sheet2`. I tried `COUNTIFS` with multiple criteria but that just gave zero count for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula in `G2` in the example below uses `COUNTA` and `FILTER` to determine how many rows match all criteria. You can adapt for various applications.  Formula has been tested in both Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets.

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(C2:C8,
       (A2:A8=E2)*(B2:B8=E3)*(IFERROR(FIND(E4,C2:C8)>0,FALSE))))
```

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Titles** | **Industry** | **Responses** |  | **Menu Selections** |  | **Count** |
| **2** | Title_3 | Industry_1 | Ans_1;Ans_10;Ans_5;Ans_11;Ans_13; |  | Title_2 |  | 2 |
| **3** | Title_2 | Industry_2 | Ans_1;Ans_10;Ans_8; |  | Industry_1 |  |  |
| **4** | Title_2 | Industry_1 | Ans_1;Ans_11; |  | Ans_11; |  |  |
| **5** | Title_3 | Industry_1 | Ans_6;Ans_11; |  |  |  |  |
| **6** | Title_5 | Industry_1 | Ans_1;Ans_11; |  |  |  |  |
| **7** | Title_5 | Industry_2 | Ans_1;Ans_11; |  |  |  |  |
| **8** | Title_2 | Industry_1 | Ans_1;Ans_11;Ans_10; |  |  |  |  |

Earlier solution using `SUMPRODUCT` works in Google Sheets but not in Microsoft Excel

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A8=E2, B2:B8=E3, IFERROR(IF(FIND(E4,C2:C8)>0,1,),))
```

Comment: Thank you. For some strange reason, this works in Google Sheets but not in Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Updated to a formula that works equally in Excel and Sheets. Left original formula at bottom in case it has value.